# Why does filtering with Python skip some entries in my list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filter

To combat lockdown boredom and hone my (very limited!) coding skills, I'm currently writing a Python program to help me solve the NYTimes Spelling Bee game: You're given seven letters and have to find all words containing these (and only these) with at least four letters, with one core letter being mandatory.

My approach is the following: Get the words corpus from ntlk as a base line and remove all entries with less than three letters. For faster processing, I split this up in lists according to wordlength, in this example the four-letter-words-list `wordList`. I make sure this is all lower-case and remove duplicates in this list.

To find the right words, I take a list containing all the letters in the alphabet, remove the seven given letters and have only the forbidden letters left, hence the name `forbiddenLettersList`.

Then I go through the entire `wordList` letter by letter in `forbiddenLettersList` and drop the found entries:

```
    for letter in forbiddenLettersList:
        for word in wordList:
            if letter in word:
                wordList.remove(word)
    return wordList
```

However, the resulting `wordList` still contains tons of entries with forbidden letters - what am I doing wrong? How can I reliably remove those unwanted elements?

Comment: Did you write this in a function?

Comment: Is it a case issue? Leading / trailing blanks? Can't tell without your data.

Comment: You are looping over `wordlist` and removing entries at the same time.  This means some entries get skipped: remove entry 2, for example and entry 3 moves into position 2, and the next entry read is what was originally entry 4.  The answers to the linked duplicates Q & As explain in detail.

Comment: @Ajay: Yes, I did.

Comment: @snakecharmerb: That makes sense! I'll head over to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating?noredirect=1&lq=1) to see whether that helps.